# Does Captain Earth borrow elements from Gurren Lagann?

Tags: gurren-lagann, captain-earth

As a viewer of both series from start to end, I can see several elements in Captain Earth that seems to "borrow" from Gurren Lagann, especially in the second half of both of the series:

- In episode 23, just before the *entangle link*, Daichi was interfered by Planetary Gears and put inside a dream where he was tempted to keep on living his normal life, not involving with the whole saving-the-world business. However, he broke out of the illusion due to the memories of his friends in his heart. This is similar to how the almost entire crew of Dai Gurren-dan got trapped in Extradimensional Labyrinth in episode 26 of Gurren Lagann and experienced their dreams being fulfilled, but managed to escape from it with the help of Kamina.
- Daichi and co. did an *entangle link* to jump from Earth to Uranus, similar to how Dai Gurren-dan jumped through dimension from Earth to Anti-Spiral's home world. They both missed on their first try and got ambushed.
- In the final battle, Daichi charged into the transformed Blume while sacrificing the expansion layer (which is assembled as the smaller mecha is launched to Tenkaidou). This is similar to the final battle between Simon and the Anti-Spiral, where outer layers of the Gurren Lagann is left behind as Simon charged in with his Lagann and destroy the Anti-Spiral.
- Kill-T-Gangs, the perceived antagonists of the series, don't have any libido (*Orgone energy*), therefore they can't reproduce, while all human has Orgone energy. This is similar to the Anti-Spirals in Gurren Lagann, who don't have any *Spiral energy* (since they purge it themselves), while human has Spiral energy. Both series feature clashes between one with the source of all-powerful energy and one without such energy.

Are these similarities normal for mecha anime, especially when the first 3 points are all focused on the last fight? Has there been any interview regarding this topic?

Comment: Gurren Lagann was like an homage to the entire shounen mecha genre, so my guess is that Captain Earth isn't directly borrowing elements from GL so much as from older shows.